# Entering systematically new columns to a dataset with month/year reference to existing column

Tags: python, append, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

My current data is looks roughly like this

```
barcode  Jan-18   Feb-18  Mar-18  Apr-18.......
11         100     150     200     250
22         500     600     700     800 
33         900     1000    1100    1200
```

now I just need to add to every date MMM-YY column two more columns (containing the same values): year and month, so it would look like that:

```
barcode  Jan-18  Jan   2018  Feb-18   Feb  2018   Mar-18   Mar    2018  
11        100    100   100   150     150    150    200     200     200
22        500    500   500   600     600    600    700     700     700
33        900    900   900   1000    1000   1000   1100    1100    1100
```

Many thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for n, col in enumerate(df.columns)[1:]:
    new_cols = col.split('-')
    for newcol in new_cols:
        df[newcol] = df.insert(n+1, newcol, df[col])
```

You'll get duplicated columns which isn't usually recommended, though.